# What is CSlistener and why is it running on port 9000 on my mac and restarts itself every time I stop it

Tags: macos, server

Context:
Woke up and couldn't start my app that uses port `9000` because address was already in use. Message on my terminal is

```
Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:9000: bind: address already in use
```

The command `netstat -anvp tcp | awk 'NR<3 || /LISTEN/'` lists a process running on port 9000 like;

```
Active Internet connections (including servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)     rhiwat shiwat    pid   epid  state    options
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.9000         *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072   1260      0 0x0080 0x00000006
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.3306         *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    997      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.33060        *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    997      0 0x0000 0x00000006
```

there are more processes listed, i just trimmed it. I can see stuff like `127.0.0.1.3306` which i think is mysql, thats fine, but the process running at `127.0.0.1.9000` is what am not sure about.
Killing the process with `sudo kill 1260`, the ID of the process is `1260` and running the command `netstat -anvp tcp | awk 'NR<3 || /LISTEN/'` lists the process again with a different process ID.

Running `sudo lsof -i TCP:9000` prints

```
php-fpm 2997 root    9u  IPv4 0xf6c73412e60c41cb      0t0  TCP localhost:cslistener (LISTEN)
php-fpm 3000 _www   10u  IPv4 0xf6c73412e60c41cb      0t0  TCP localhost:cslistener (LISTEN)
php-fpm 3001 _www   10u  IPv4 0xf6c73412e60c41cb      0t0  TCP localhost:cslistener (LISTEN)
```

So after seeing this printed I googled `cslistener`, notice that there is a string `TCP localhost:cslistener` in what's printed.

One find suggested looking for it in the file `/etc/services` and sure I found it, the lines looked like

```
...
cslistener      9000/udp     # CSlistener
cslistener      9000/tcp     # CSlistener
...
```

So, my question is, what is `cslistener` and why is it running on port 9000 and restarting itself everytime i kill it.

Comment: This is not an answer about what `cslistener` is, but how I managed to free port 9000 in my case.

It looks like php-fpm was using the port 9000, so I went to the `/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php-fpm.d` file and edited the `www.conf` file. I changed the line

```listen = 127.0.0.1:9000```
to 
```listen = 127.0.0.1:9324``` 
_(you can use any port u want)_ 
and killed the process that was running on port 9000, which restarted itself but using port `9324`

Comment: In my case it was the php installed with brew, it will be enough to stop the service. If you use php in docker.